# Will the synchronize method throw EOF Exception?

Tags: java, exception, synchronized

I have a synchronize method, in whoich i am using datainputstream.readfully() .Its throwing me the "EOF exception". Why the reallyfully method throws EOF when it is still inside the synchronize method? below is the code for reference

```
private static synchronized String getTransactionId() {
       try {
          String txnId_fname = SiteConfiguration.getInstance().getProperty("TRANSACTION.INFO_FILE", //
                  LaneProcessor.DEFAULT_TRANSACTION_ID_FILE_NAME);

          File tmpFile = new File(txnId_fname);
          if (!tmpFile.exists()) {
              tmpFile.createNewFile();
          }
          else {

             long sz = tmpFile.length();
             if ( 12 == sz ) {
                // read the transaction id from the file, the ID must be 12 bytes long to be valid.
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(tmpFile));

                byte[] datainBytes = new byte[dis.available()];
                dis.readFully(datainBytes);
                transactionIdLog = new String(datainBytes, 0, datainBytes.length);

                if ( Stringer.isNumeric(transactionIdLog))
                  { 

                    transactionId = Long.valueOf(transactionIdLog);
                  }

                dis.close();
                //log.debug("transaction id from the existing file"+transactionId);
             }
          }


          transactionId = ConvertUtils.incrementLong(transactionId);
          transactionIdLog = Long.toString(transactionId);
            transactionIdLog = Stringer.zpad(transactionIdLog, 12);

          _out = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);
          _out.write(transactionIdLog.getBytes());
          _out.flush();
          _out.close();

      }
      catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("Error in transaction id generation" + e.getMessage(), e);
      }
      return transactionIdLog;
    }
```

Comment: The contract for `available` is that it returns an *estimate* of the number of bytes available; if you try to read that many bytes, the program won't block but it may read fewer bytes than `available` says.   If `available`'s result is too high, then `readFully` could get an EOF exception.  Unfortunately, I tried looking at the source of `FileInputStream.available` to see how it worked, but it's `native`, so I can't tell whether it could return a "too large" value.  All I can say is, based on the javadoc, I don't think your code is guaranteed to work.

Comment: @ajb Please post your comment as an answer as it's the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

The contract for available is that it returns an *estimate* of the number of bytes available; if you try to read that many bytes, the program won't block but it may read fewer bytes than available says. If available's result is too high, then `readFully` could get an EOF exception. Unfortunately, I tried looking at the source of `FileInputStream.available` to see how it worked, but it's native, so I can't tell whether it could return a "too large" value. All I can say is, based on the javadoc, I don't think your code is guaranteed to work.

To see whether this really is the problem, I'd recommend having the program output `datainBytes.length` after the array is created, and then check that against the actual file size.

Answer (score 0):

> Will the synchronize method throw EOF Exception?

Literally No.  Any exception in the method will be caught and logged.  So it won't propagate an `EOFException`.  What is more, there is no `throw new EOFException(...)`.

But could your method catch `EOFException` and log it?  I think the answer is Yes!

The `readFully` method will throws `EOFException` if it cannot fill the buffer, and you have set the buffer size to the number of bytes that `available()` says are readable.  But consider this scenario:

1. Your application executes to the point where `available()` returns.
2. Your application is paused (e.g. by the OS scheduler).
3. Some other application truncates the file.
4. Your application is resumed, and calls `readFully` ... only to discover that there are ZERO bytes to be read.
5. EOFException ...

---

This illustrates the point that the result of `isAvailable()` is only a hint.  You can't entirely rely on it.

But, I don't think it is technically possible to code that method in such a way that an EOFException cannot occur.  You certainly can't do it without some kind of file locking ... to prevent other applications truncating the file while your application is reading it.